# When using resource in rails how can it work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I understand when using `resources :users`

It creates seven routes.

Then `localhost:3000/users/1`: How it is mapped to "GET /users/1 show"? Why not to patch or delete?

Comment: Its very unclear what you are asking, did you try reading the docs? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: when i request localhost/user/1 rails routes just scanning resource :user from top to bottom ex) show -> new -> create -> update -> destory
show is top the routes then i go to user/1 -> show user '1' ?

Comment: Because browsers do `GET` by default. Use of other verbs requires either custom request code or something more interesting than a link in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something you don't seem be aware of which is the [HTTP methods](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html), also known as verbs.

Yes, the `show` request, and `update` request may seem similar, but they are divided by HTTP verb as following:

```
==========================================
|HTTP Method | Format     | Route        |
=============|============|===============
|   GET      | /users/:id | users#show   |
=============|============|===============
|   PUT      | /users/:id | users#update |
==========================================
```

So, it is basically the HTTP verb that differentiates between both.

And for `destroy`, the HTTP verb `DELETE` is used.

```
==========================================
|HTTP Method | Format     | Route        |
=============|============|===============
|   DELETE   | /users/:id | users#destroy|
==========================================
```

Comment: The proper name is [HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: Yup, it is. My mistake.

Comment: when i just request /usrs/1 how can it figure out GET request in rails

Comment: Whenever you type a URL in the browser, it almost goes for the GET request. And when you submit a form, it may or may not go for a POST request on the server.

Comment: You write `http://www.google.com` in the browser, you are sending a GET request to Google.

Comment: And you can not send a POST request by writing some URL in the browser, you either have to use a form, or use something like curl.